# How to remove the toast like popup in BottomNavigationView when long press the item?

Tags: android, kotlin, popup, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

How to remove the toast like popup in material bottom navigation view `BottomNavigationView` occurs when we long press the single item .The demo image attached below[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is `tooltip`, It can be disabled by calling `TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(view, null)` on each menu item.

```
bottomNavigationView
    .menu.forEach {
            TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(bottomNavigationView.findViewById<View>(it.itemId), null)
        }
```

There's a possible chance that the above code won't work, when the `bottomNavigationView` sets the `tooltip` text after you set it as `null`. You can override the `longClickListener` on the menu item itself, so it won't show a `tooltip` text.

```
bottomNavigationView
    .menu.forEach {
        bottomNavigationView.findViewById<View>(it.itemId).setOnLongClickListener {
            // add any code which you want to execute on long click
            true
            }
    }
```

Comment: Not working. Still Showing the Tooltip when long press